# How can protein allergens be passed from mother to baby via breastmilk is proteins are broken down after ingestion?

Tags: proteins, allergies

All over the Internet new mothers are urged to avoid dairy products, a slew of vegetables and even beef if their child displays symptoms of reflux.

In the case of dairy, for instance, it is said that an allergic reaction can be caused by specific proteins that exist in cow's milk.

What I don't get is this: aren't ingested proteins broken up into their constituent amino acids, which are then recombined, presumably somewhere in the milk-producing glands, to create new proteins that are then passed on to the child through the mother's milk?

If that is the case, the original, allergy-inducing proteins should be long gone by then, right? If that is indeed the case, then what is causing the allergy and is there an allergy in the first place or could the cause be something else?

Comment: What means "all over the internet"? The usual unscientific websites which claim nonsense? Or are there credible scientific reports?

Comment: Well, I try to avoid obviously pseudo-scientific sources, but even the NHS has a [web page](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/eat-well/milk-and-dairy-nutrition/?tabname=food-and-diet) that states that cow's milk in the mother's diet can "rarely" be passed on to the child through best milk.